# anyway to strech a object to the mouse? in cpp & SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

https://gyazo.com/0952a960bd7f9e5c9c5e1fe71d0f0b45 I want to get a punching effect similar to this.
what I currently got is

is there any way to replicate this? and how will it be done? 
the problem with the code given is when it reaches the x coords. it becomes very thin. any clue and how will it be fixed?

I am checking if button left is being pressed. and if it is being pressed 
it calculates the distance between the mouse and the area that it is being pressed.
and then set the scale to the absolute value of y.

## include "quarks.h" is my little framework i created.

this is the effect given  https://gyazo.com/fd46b85cd69d95d05d2a8e6f184c4e06

I hope somebody can help me

````cpp
#include "quarks.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>

#include <cmath>
static constexpr float pi = 3.14159265359f;

static constexpr float to_degree(float radian)
{
    return radian * (180.f / pi);
}


int main() {
    QuarksSDK::CreateWindow window;
    window.windowSettings(VideoMode(1000, 900), "Hello.", Style::Close);
    float grid =64;
    RectangleShape click(Vector2f(42, grid));
    click.setPosition(window.getSize().x / 2, window.getSize().y / 2);
    click.setOrigin({ std::round(click.getLocalBounds().width / 2.f), std::round(click.getLocalBounds().height / 2.f) });
    Clock clock;
    QuarksSDK::movement mov;
    sf::Clock tickClock;
    sf::Time timeSinceLastUpdate = sf::Time::Zero;
    sf::Time duration = sf::Time::Zero;
    sf::Time TimePerFrame = sf::seconds(1.f / 60.f);
    QuarksAnimator::easeQuarks ease;

    while (window.isWindowOpen()) {
        window.pollEvents();

        if (Mouse::isButtonPressed(Mouse::Left)) {
            if (clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() < 1.f) {
                Vector2f distance = Vector2f(click.getPosition().x - Mouse::getPosition(*window.window).x, click.getPosition().y - Mouse::getPosition(*window.window).y);
                float angle = to_degree(atan2f(distance.y, distance.x));



                click.setRotation(angle + 90);


                click.setSize(Vector2f(grid, abs(distance.y)));
                cout << angle << endl;
            }
            else {
                click.setSize(Vector2f(grid, grid));
                clock.restart();

            }
        }
        else {
            click.setSize(Vector2f(grid, grid));


        }
        mov.SmoothMovement(click);
        window.clear();
        window.draw(click);
        window.display();
    }


}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Code fixed. #include "quarks.h"

````
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>

#include <cmath>
static constexpr float pi = 3.14159265359f;

static constexpr float to_degree(float radian)
{
    return radian * (180.f / pi);
}


int main() {
    QuarksSDK::CreateWindow window;
    window.windowSettings(VideoMode(1000, 900), "Hello.", Style::Close);
    float grid =64;
    RectangleShape click(Vector2f(42, grid));
    click.setPosition(window.getSize().x / 2, window.getSize().y / 2);
    click.setOrigin({ std::round(click.getLocalBounds().width / 2.f), std::round(click.getLocalBounds().height / 2.f) });
    Clock clock;
    QuarksSDK::movement mov;
    sf::Clock tickClock;
    sf::Time timeSinceLastUpdate = sf::Time::Zero;
    sf::Time duration = sf::Time::Zero;
    sf::Time TimePerFrame = sf::seconds(1.f / 60.f);
    QuarksAnimator::easeQuarks ease;

    while (window.isWindowOpen()) {
        window.pollEvents();

        if (Mouse::isButtonPressed(Mouse::Left)) {

                Vector2f distance = Vector2f(click.getPosition().x - Mouse::getPosition(*window.window).x, click.getPosition().y - Mouse::getPosition(*window.window).y);
                float angle = to_degree(atan2f(distance.y, distance.x));



                click.setRotation(angle + 90);


                click.setSize(Vector2f(grid,sqrt(distance.y * distance.y + distance.x * distance.x)));
                cout << angle << endl;
            } 

        else {
            click.setSize(Vector2f(grid, grid));


        }
        mov.SmoothMovement(click);
        window.clear();
        window.draw(click);
        window.display();
    }


}```
````